# How to calculate difference between two dates in textboxes in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net

I need to find difference between two dates in textboxes. the difference should be in years, months and dates.
I try to use Datediff but it didn't works with months and days

```
Dim y_diff As Integer
    Dim m_diff As Integer
    Dim d_diff As Integer
    Dim date1 As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox1.Text)
    Dim dob As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text)
    Response.Write("Today date is " & Today.Date & "<br>")
    y_diff = DateDiff("yyyy", dob, date1)

    m_diff = DateDiff("m", dob, date1) / y_diff / 12

    d_diff = DateDiff("d", dob, date1) / 365
    Response.Write("Difference in year" & y_diff & "<br>" & "months" & m_diff & "<br>" & d_diff & "<br>")
```

how can i get it correctly?

Comment: what doesn't work? and did you try to use the TimeSpan class also?

Comment: What did you get and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
TimeSpan diff = date1.Subtract(dob);
long Years = Convert.ToInt64(diff.TotalDays) / 365;
long Months = (Convert.ToInt64(diff.TotalDays) - (Years * 365)) / 30;
long Days = Convert.ToInt64(diff.TotalDays) - ((Years * 365) + (Months * 30)); 
int totaldays = diff.Days + 1;
```

It will perfectly for you.Kindly let me know if get helped.

Comment: I use it but it gives me the correct results for years only
for example 
first date: 1/1/2014
second date: 1/1/2011
results will be:
3 years    36 months     1096 days

Comment: .@user3454142 i have edited my Answer. Now check it.

Comment: still wrong results with substract
6/1/2014
10/4/2013
days-5        months -4     years 1